# White screen page whenever new build and deploy - Reactjs project on AKS

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, deployment

We have react.js project works perfectly on Kubernetes(AKS) whenever we build and deploy, the active end-user faces white screen and works only after hard refresh of browser. We could see Main, chunk.js files referred to previous build, fails with 404 in pod logs. Newly initiated request reaches the proper Main and chunk.js files and serves properly after few seconds. Hence we have many end users impacted during deployment.
Env: Nginx(pod) acts as reverse proxy + Web-client (Express & React)  running on Azure Kubernetes

Comment: I would guess you have the webapp in a Deployment, and thus there are Pods from the old ReplicaSet and Pods from the new ReplicaSet and since a Service round-robins between them, it fetches `index.html` from the old (thus, pointing at the old bundled JS) and then the next request comes in to the new for the old bundle filename which is 404; we solved that problem by changing the `selector:` on the Service to atomically switch traffic over, so it no longer simultaneously matched both ReplicaSets

Comment: Could you kindly explain which Service do you mean to change ?  Are you talking about the deployment strategy approach ?

Comment: the `Service` through which your Ingress or NodePort reaches those Pods -- there is, to the best of my knowledge, no such thing as exposing a Pod directly outside of a cluster

Comment: If you are running your _own_ nginx, separate from an Ingress or (LoadBalancer|NodePort) mechanism, you can actually likely also trick nginx into proxying upstream for any 404 chunk files, but it would be a ton more work to figure out the details to get that right

Comment: We have Service with type as NodePort and then Nginx to expose outside. We could see the 404 chunk files logs in webapp pod. So you mean to have selector in service of webapp to handle this issue?

Comment: I think what @mdaniel mentioned is covered in kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service). So if you create service with `selector: app: MyApp` it creates a new Service object named "my-service", which targets any Pod with the `app=MyApp` label. So with this your older pods won't get any traffic after new deploy, and there shouldn't be any 404 issue. Could you try to add that selector to your webapp service and your new deployments and check if it works?

Comment: We have Service for this webapp already in place which holds  `selector: app: app-name`  And the Service name is mapped  on the nginx (rewrite rule).  So the request is passed via service to the pods. But still we are facing the issue.